# Can someone please explain this diagram from the book 'HBase: the Definitive Guide'?

Tags: hbase

Reading through the book *'HBase: the Definitive Guide'* there is this example on page 19:

[image: HBase: The Definitive Guide, Figure 1-4]

It is accompanied by the following explanation:

> Figure 1-4 helps to visualize how different rows are in a normal database as opposed
>   to the column-oriented design of HBase. You should think about rows and columns
>   not being arranged like the classic spreadsheet model, but rather use a tag metaphor,
>   that is, information is available under a specific tag.
>
> The "NULL?" in Figure 1-4 indicates that, for a database with a fixed
>   schema, you have to store NULLs where there is no value, but for
>   HBase’s storage architectures, you simply omit the whole column; in
>   other words, NULLs are free of any cost: they do not occupy any
>   storage space.

It appears to be demonstrating that the same column (B) can be stored in different column families, however I am unclear about the following...

1. Why is the row-C-column-C-value pointing to a 'huge value'?
2. Is there a reason why row D is left out of the HBase equivalent?
3. Is it significant that row-A-column-A is pointing to row-B-column-B? Does HBase traverse some linked-list to go through the different columns?

Comment: I don't understand the diagram but that description is really weird, it seems to conflate the "logical view" ("normal database", " database with a fixed schema": relational, tabular, spreadsheet-like) and the "implementation" (where "you simply omit the whole column; stuff does not occupy any storage space") and then concludes that there is some advantage for HBase. That's confusing at best, disingenious at worst.

Comment: To answer 3.: no HBase doesn't traverse a linked list, and I have no idea what that's meant to represent. To answer 1. and 2.: I have no idea what that's meant to represent :). This is not a good diagram.

Comment: Much appreciated. For the most part I found the book does a good job with its visual aids so this one surprised me